# How to update ECR login token without regenerate every 12 hours?

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, docker, registry, token

Followed this guide to try to set the ECR token helper, but didn't work well.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/

After 12 hours, the token went away and didn't generate a new one.

Is it possible to generate it in a easy way?

Comment: Did you follow the section titled "Manual ECR authentication with the Docker CLI" or "Using Credential Helper on Linux/Mac and Windows"?  You'd need to follow that second section in order to set up the credential helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, You have to re-generate ECR token after every 16 hours (or 8 hours I do not remember the figure)

For this, you can use any method like CRON job, Jenkins jobs or whatever. But there is no setting to set age for the token in ECR.

I not seen the link you provided but looks this is some kind of Jenkins job. If the job ran successfully, Set a periodically build triggers for the job. In configuring jobs page of Jenkins there is an option "Build periodically" you need to specify CRON like settings.

If your job itself is felling check your keys/roles attached to the machine. Still, your luck not helped Post Jenkins console log here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if many hosts need to get login to the ECR, how to deal with those hosts? The Jenkins will work for its server only.

Comment: In that case, you need to login to ECR from each host. Maybe add slave in Jenkins and execute jobs on a slave (if your hosts are limited in number) or do ssh and execute login command one by one on each host (of course programmatically :)).

Comment: I choose docker registry:) Thanks.

Comment: that's better option :P

Comment: Yea, it's a big pain to use AWS ECR with token stupid regeneration every 12 hrs. Especially if you have several servers (CI server, CI agents, Rancher etc).